# aapt.exe crashes when I try to export my Android application from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt

Since I updated two days ago my Android SDK to version API 14 I'm getting troubles using Eclipse Helios on my Windows 7 x64 laptop.

When I try to export a project everything is ok until I get to press the "finish" button: then a popup appears saying "aapt.exe has stopped working" and I can't get my signed apk; the project doesn't return errors and compiles as usual.

I googled to find a solution but nothing of the solutions i found worked:

- I cleaned the project (Project>Clean)
- I disabled the automatic build (Project>Build Automatically)
- I deleted all the imported libraries (Right click on the project>Properties>Java Build Path)
- I updated all the related software (Help>Check for updates)
- I put logcat mode on verbose
- I deleted my .9.png drawables and readded to my project

These are all the solutions I found related to aapt.exe issues. Do you have any other suggestion?

PS: I'm also getting a layout issue with all my .9.png files that are not displayed correctly, but I don't know if it's related.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found a solution in Window>Preferences>Android>Build by setting "Build output" on **Normal** and then Project>Clean>Clean All.

I don't know if this is the definitive solution but it made me able to export my apk with the proper .9.png drawable layout.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So weird, I am able to consistently produce broken .apks w/o the Clean All. But if I don't do Clean all and I just run the app via Eclipse, it works with the latest code changes.

Comment: as crazy as it sounds - this actually seems to work!

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem when I tried to add `id` as `<resources>` as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id).

```
<resources>
  <item type="id" name="button_ok" />
  <item type="id" name="dialog_exit" />
</resources>
```

When I deleted this, the build was successful.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem defining a menu item like this:

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_help" 
    android:showAsAction="never|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_label_help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_help"
/>
```

I was just missing the icon file ic_menu_help, but instead of giving me a nice message that the image file was missing, it crashes aapt.

Comment: It seems if a icon is referenced from `menu` and it's later deleted, eclipse doesn't recognize it, stops appt instead.