# SherlockActionBar: Export signed apk, then Eclipse crashes :(

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, actionbarsherlock

Today I finished testing my new android app..

I use SherlockActionBar.

Import as an /library

My OS is Ubuntu 12.10 64bit..

I can build the .apk from Eclipse and the app runs on my Android 2.3.3(mobile) and my Android 4.0(tablet).

But when I try to: `Android tools -> Export signed application package`, 
then Eclipse crashes :(

I get this error:(before the Export/crash)

```
Invalid ZIP archive: /home/voidcode/Ubuntu One/workspace/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c/library/bin/library.jar
```

This is the **error log** I find in the Eclipse-folder after the crash: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1677938/

My **AndroidManifest.xml** look like this:

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="4"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
> ```

And my **project.properties** look like this:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-14
android.library.reference.1=../JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c/library
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may want to check a couple of things in your project.

- Your *project.properties* file targets Android API14, but your manifest targets API15. These should be the same
- Sherlock ActionBar only works on API7+. This may be your issue actually. Try changing `android:minSdkVersion="4"` to `android:minSdkVersion="7"`

  - Obviously this will not allow anything prior to Android 2.1, but you'll still target nearly 100% of the ecosystem.

If that doesn't work, I've had lots of trouble with this as well and the exporting packages solutions are fairly random.

My general solution is to disable the auto build, clean it and then manually build the library projects.

For example

- Under the **Project** menu
- Uncheck **Build automatically**
- Then **Project** > **Clean...**
- On this window, uncheck **Start build immediately**
- Choose **Clean all projects** and click **OK**
- Select your *Sherlock ActionBar* project
- Do **Project** > **Build project** (NOT Build All).

  - This will build ONLY this one library
  - Do this for any library projects you have included.
- Click Now, export your project as a signed APK.

That generally works for me and stops a lot of the unexplained export issues.

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to recheck **Build automatically** while coding if that was the issue.

Comment: This strategy worked for me as well. It looks like it's the indexer of Eclipse that is failing while jar files are being rebuilt with an "invalid zip error" though

Comment: @Kirk Wow, this problem had caused so many crashes that by the time i was trying the "build project (Not build all) etc" i was expecting yet ANOTHER crash but no, worked perfectly. Praise the sun!

Comment: Where is "Start build immediately"?. I tried this but then my project can't import Action Bar Sherlock. Thanks!

Comment: @eyyo You must uncheck Build Automatically first for that option to appear. However you don't need to worry about this until you are exporting as an APK.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Mac, check this question: [Exporting APK from eclipse (ADT) silently crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752270/exporting-apk-from-eclipse-adt-silently-crashes)

Basically, disable *Build Automatically*