# Why does ADT let's me export once. 2nd Export it crashes OSX 10.6

Tags: eclipse, osx-snow-leopard, adt

I have a weird problem since a few days. After exporting a project for android once it works fine the 2nd export I do eclipse crashes with this error:

```
Identifier:      org.eclipse.eclipse
Version:         3.8 (3.8)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [269]

Date/Time:       2013-03-12 21:36:13.365 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          321292 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           3
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  44806 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2
Anonymous UUID:                      52A136CA-CDAE-4661-B166-51B04A18C21C

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000a, 0x000000011f1c965f
Crashed Thread:  46  Java: ModalContext
```

Any clues. Running: adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219

SIGBUS looks like bad RAM but then other things would act up aswell?
B

Answer (score 3):

I guess that's random. As mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752270/exporting-apk-from-eclipse-adt-silently-crashes) it looks like it can happen if eclipse is building your project at the same time as you're exporting it. You could try to disable the "build automatically" option in eclipse while you're exporting it.