# During export of signed app, eclipse crashes

Tags: android, crash, dalvik

I have an android application that I exported a signed version perfectly on March 17, 2013. Then on March 19, 2013 I updated the Facebook SDK and Android SDK Manager, then tried to export my a signed version of my app again. First mistake.

Now I've been experiencing one of the two issues ever since and I can't export a new signed version of my app to re-upload the Google Play store.

1. Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
2. or my Android Application Crashes when I'm exporting it.

I've tried numerous solutions I've found on the web and still am experiencing no luck. I even removed and re-installed Eclipse, the ADT, and Facebook SDK. Still, I'm having issues.

Eclipse actually crashes which is really odd. Any ideas?

Update:
So, I am no longer getting the "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" any more on export of signed app. Eclipse just crashes on export of signed app. Any ideas? I have all the latest software: eclipse, facebook sdk, android sdk, etc. I'm running the latest version of  Mac OS X.

Comment: there are some where problem in your code that lead the conversion of code to byte format

Comment: Have you added any new Jars to your build path?

Comment: So, I am no longer getting the "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" any more. Eclipse just crashes on export of signed app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

So here's how I fixed the issue, I'm sure someone will have this issue again. what worked for me was turning off automatic build. Something so small. Thanks for the help!

*Also, the answers above worked for others.

Comment: Turning off automatic build and cleaning the workspace worked for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: To turn off automatic build, Project -> uncheck 'Build Automatically'

Answer (score 5):

I also experienced this one. Try doing project->clean to your project and restart your eclipse workspace.

If it doesn't work read this thread it might help you.

["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" -- on export only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161852/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-export-only)

Comment: That linked helped but didn't have my answer. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove all except the "Android X.Y", click OK.

Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your project and click OK.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. But I know it worked for others. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Disable project/build Automatically before export an apk.
[image]

[Exporting APK from eclipse (ADT) silently crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752270/exporting-apk-from-eclipse-adt-silently-crashes/27008240#27008240)

Answer (score 0):

this might be because there are libraries that have classes that have alike names or different android target version

Answer (score 0):

For me, quitting Dropbox on Mac OS X Yosemite helped (I clicked on "Report" and the stacktrace mentioned a Dropbox thread).