# Eclipse crashes however creating a signed apk

Tags: java, android, apk, workspace, signed

I just created a new workspace for eclipse. I am using Mac system. When i try to create a signed apk of an application in this new workspace it crashes Eclipse and take me out of it. There is popup window open which request to "reopen Eclipse" & close Eclipse.

Can any body help me out of here. is it temporary error or serious issue. how can i resolve it and make a signed apk.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: See this post > http://stackoverflow.com/a/13583672/2035885.
It will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Please uncheck build automatically option shown under project tab in eclipse.