# AAPT.EXE stopped running in eclipse(ANDROID)

Tags: android, aapt

I am facing a problem with AAPT while executing an android project. I have done the following steps:

Project > Clean

and

Window > Preferences > Android > Build > Normal

However, it doesn't affect the project. The attributes are not generated in R.java file.

Comment: did you try restarting eclipse ?

Comment: Does your problem view show errors in your xml files?

Comment: yes i have tried when i clean the project the it was show a message "AAPT stopped running"

Comment: Same problme, can anyone told about fixes...tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843436/aapt-exe-crashes-when-i-try-to-export-my-android-application-from-eclipse : not worknig

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21108787/1329126

Comment: Try This

goto project properties > Android > android Build Target > change Target  to higher version

Answer (score 1):

when I encounter that problem I just remove all the projects and then create a new one
and copy again the files from new project. But first check the xml codes before copying.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16831707/1237656). This issue sometimes comes with the platform-tools.

if not it might be due to some bugs in your XML. If so the solution is in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/utnUiNIGgmA).