# Android appt.exe has stopped working

Tags: java, android, sdk

Hi I am new to android and am doing some new basic projects. Whenever I try to save a project the alert box saying "unfortunately appt.exe has stopped working appears" and all of a sudden there are many errors that can be seen. I can also see that the R.java file disappears automatically and I dont know what to do next. I read somewhere that to delete the id in style, but cannot see any Id in my styles.xml file. I even deleted the whole SDK and downloaded and started from scratch, so would love if I could find any solution to this annoying problem.

Comment: This has already been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513950/aapt-exe-stopped-running-in-eclipseandroid

Comment: I tried it by removing the eclipse uninstally java jdk and jre and then tried again. It worked apparantly.