# Android and Eclipse: 9 patch resource bug, causing aapt to crash when trying to export

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

I've just experience this bug where aapt crashes when I try to export the android project to apk. Almost like this one [aapt.exe crashes when I try to export my Android application from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843436/aapt-exe-crashes-when-i-try-to-export-my-android-application-from-eclipse). I only encountered this bug because I've updated my Android SDK Tool to version 22.6.2 and eclipse to [ADT Bundle 22.6.2](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

The **difference** is that in my case, even if I delete the 9 patch resources and readd them, the problem will just comeback. I Also tried redoing all my 9patch png with no successful result. I've researched and tried the different cases that will cause the aapt to crashes like this one ([Eclipse and Android SDK issue "aapt.exe has stopped"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828642/eclipse-and-android-sdk-issue-aapt-exe-has-stopped)) and I've concluded that only 9 patch png causes the problem.

Do anyone know other ways to fix this bug because I really need to include the 9 patch in the project, or if not, any good alternative for the 9patch png? Lastly, is this a new bug since the 22.6.2 release was just released a week ago?

Note: if I delete all 9patch png resources the problem will not occured, but I need to include these 9patch pngs in the exported apk.

Edit: So in Window > Preferences > Android > Build > Build Ouput I picked normal. Then I remove the 9 patch and readd them then in the error log I got the following (note that @drawable/bubble_me is a 9patch png so where the f*ck I gonna put that #?):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@drawable/bubble_me' must start with #
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:71)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:248)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:782)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:86)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:504)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.changed(GraphicalEditorPart.java:725)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onTargetChange(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1196)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.onDescriptorsChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:916)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateInitUiRootNode(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:835)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$TargetListener.updateEditor(GraphicalEditorPart.java:953)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$TargetListener.onTargetLoaded(GraphicalEditorPart.java:917)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$11.run(AdtPlugin.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.EventLoopProgressMonitor.runEventLoop(EventLoopProgressMonitor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.EventLoopProgressMonitor.isCanceled(EventLoopProgressMonitor.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.isCanceled(ThreadJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.waitForRun(ThreadJob.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.joinRun(ThreadJob.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.begin(ImplicitJobs.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.beginRule(JobManager.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkManager.checkIn(WorkManager.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.prepareOperation(Workspace.java:2283)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2340)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.WorkspaceOperationRunner.run(WorkspaceOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.WorkspaceOperationRunner.run(WorkspaceOperationRunner.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.executeOperation(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.saveDocument(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.performSave(AbstractTextEditor.java:5073)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSave(AbstractTextEditor.java:4863)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.doSave(StructuredTextEditor.java:1916)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.doSave(AndroidXmlEditor.java:626)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.doSave(CommonXmlEditor.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper$2.run(SaveableHelper.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper$5.run(SaveableHelper.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1818)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1815)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.savePart(SaveableHelper.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveSaveable(WorkbenchPage.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3782)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SaveHandler.execute(SaveHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1525)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4611)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4977)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Exception` in the following line...

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@drawable/bubble_me' must start with #
```

Saying that, a `Color` value must start with `#`.

Suppose, your `Color` value is

```
FFFFFF
```

then proper format to put that color in XML is

```
#FFFFFF
```

Where, color value `FFFFFF` starts with `#`.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is @drawable/bubble_me is a 9patch png. It is not an xml file, so where I gonna put that # sign? In short I think it was not supposed to happen.

Comment: you are saying, its a 9patch image but your log saying its a `Color`...please, check your resource carefully.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, and I've checked, it is impossible for me to have a @drawable/bubble_me that is not an image, I arrange my res and I'm 100% sure that all files in my drawable/ is all image, additionally, I put all my animation in anim/, all my layout inside layout, all menus in menus/, etc.